# Rails 3.2.8, only restartting the server will un- cache models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, model

I have a rails app running on rails 3.2.8.

The models will only update if I restart the server, any changes made to them simply won't show up until the server is restarted.

I'm running in development and cache classes is switched off.

Is anyone else having this issues, I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

I've re-installed rvm, ruby and my gemset.

I have tried everything I can think of to fix it. Thanks to everyone having a look.

EDIT: I've added loads of config details below...

development.rb

```
XXXXX::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yyyy.xxxx.net' }

  #this is an attempt to fix the issues, didn't work
  config.to_prepare do
    ['algorithm', 'key_dates', 'roles', 'status'].each do | file_name |
      require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/user/#{file_name}.rb"
    end
  end

end
```

My user model has some modules included like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Status, Roles, KeyDates, Algorithm
  #.....
end
```

The modules are defined like this

```
module User::Status

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      extend ClassMethods
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end
  #.....
end
```

Application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'csv'
require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end
module XXXXX
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
    config.to_prepare do
      Devise::Mailer.layout "mailout"
      Devise::Mailer.helper :application
    end
  end
end
```

GemLock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.3)
    activemodel (3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
    activesupport (3.2.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.8)
    arel (3.0.2)
    aws-sdk (1.5.2)
      httparty (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
    devise (2.1.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.7)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1.1)
    devise_invitable (1.0.2)
      devise (>= 2.0.0)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    faker (1.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    heroku (2.25.0)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      netrc (~> 0.7.1)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
    hike (1.2.1)
    httparty (0.8.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.5)
    launchy (2.1.0)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.3.6)
    multi_xml (0.5.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    netrc (0.7.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.2)
    orm_adapter (0.0.7)
    paperclip (2.7.0)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    pg (0.13.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.8)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activerecord (= 3.2.8)
      activeresource (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.8)
    railties (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcarpet (1.17.2)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rubyzip (0.9.8)
    sass (3.1.18)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sequel (3.20.0)
    sinatra (1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.6)
    taps (0.3.24)
      rack (>= 1.0.1)
      rest-client (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7.0)
      sequel (~> 3.20.0)
      sinatra (~> 1.0.0)
    thor (0.16.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    uuidtools (2.1.2)
    warden (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  aws-sdk
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  devise
  devise_invitable
  faker
  heroku
  jquery-rails
  mysql2
  paperclip (~> 2.7)
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.8)
  redcarpet (= 1.17.2)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  taps
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: are your models declared inside a plugin in `vendor/plugins/whatever`? The same happens to me when I change the models/controllers inside a plugin.

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: If you ever solved this, I'd love to hear the solution. I'm having the same problem--only models won't uncache; controllers and the rest work fine.

Comment: @Pablo, that's by design.  all vendor/ and lib/ files are loaded only once, at startup.  Files in app/, however, should be refreshed on every page request (if there's any change in them, as Perello points out below).

Answer (score 2):

it is difficult to make sharp advice without seeing your project files (especially Gemfile, config/environments/development.rb, application.rb) but you can always generate brand new rails project and in few minutes transmit one-by-one your current project files to recently created one to determine exact gem or file causing the problem. after that it would be much easier to fix it, i hope. it is kind of brut force but can help in knockdown-situations

Comment: Cheers, I've popped loads of details into the post like config and gemfiles.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be partially cancelled with reload!. Here you have an incompatible gem(with rails 3.2) recharging only the modified class in dev Env. You may find an equivalent. Or make it compatible.

https://github.com/paneq/active_reload

You can also combine reload! with guard.  https://github.com/guard/guard

Do the server say development mode when it starts ? (i guess you are asking him to start in development mode, but does it really start in dev mode ?).

**UPDATE :**

Explanation about rails 3.2 (official site):

> The most noticeable new feature is that development mode got a ton and
>   a half faster. Inspired by Active Reload, we now only reload classes
>   from files you’ve actually changed. The difference is dramatic on a
>   larger application. cf : http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/20/rails-3-2-0-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store/

So for some reason rails can't detect the changes on your file system.

**UPDATE 2 :**

Check if your sources aren't in an invalid folder( from a linux point of view). I mean C:\invalid linux folder\something\rails\my_apps  may work if rails use relative paths (don't know for sure). But if the rails reloading use an absolute path whatever the reason, you are screwed.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your `config/environments/development.rb` with mine:

```
SampleApp::Application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.domain = '.lvh.me'
end
```

Comment: Thannks, I've popped my dev file in and edit, it all looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on development.rb:

config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false